# In Pyspark, unstructured data, how to retain column value as 1 if the previous record has 1 from unstructured dataframe (i.e) no partition column

Tags: sorting, pyspark, window, partitioning, unstructured-data

I have a 58 GB dataframe with one column called "value" created from reading a unstructured .sql file which is basically a MySql log dump file. It looks like below.

Please note the column "value" is only shown partially as required for the question. The columns row_idx , DDL_IND_TEMP & DDL_IND are created by me in order to achieve my requirement, which is given below.

```
+--------------------+-------+------------+-------+
|               value|row_idx|DDL_IND_TEMP|DDL_IND|
+--------------------+-------+------------+-------+
|                    |      1|        NULL|   NULL|
|-- MySQL dump 10....|      2|        NULL|   NULL|
|                  --|      3|        NULL|   NULL|
|-- Host: 192.168....|      4|        NULL|   NULL|
|-- --------------...|      5|        NULL|   NULL|
|-- Server version...|      6|        NULL|   NULL|
|                    |      7|        NULL|   NULL|
|/*!40111 SET @OLD...|     17|        NULL|   NULL|
|                    |     18|        NULL|   NULL|
|-- Table structur...|     22|        NULL|   NULL|
|                  --|     23|        NULL|   NULL|
|                    |     24|        NULL|   NULL|
|DROP TABLE IF EXI...|     25|        NULL|   NULL|
|/*!40101 SET @sav...|     26|        NULL|   NULL|
|/*!40101 SET char...|     27|        NULL|   NULL|
|                    |     28|        NULL|   NULL|
|CREATE TABLE `use...|     29|           1|      1|
|  `id` int(11) NO...|     30|        NULL|      1|
|  `number` varcha...|     31|        NULL|      1|
|  `content` varch...|     32|        NULL|      1|
|  `time` datetime...|     33|        NULL|      1|
|   PRIMARY KEY (`...|     34|        NULL|      1|
|) ENGINE=InnoDB A...|     35|        NULL|      1|
|/*!40101 SET char...|     36|        NULL|      1|
|                    |     37|        NULL|      1|
|                  --|     38|        NULL|      1|
|-- Dumping data f...|     39|           0|      0|
|                  --|     40|        NULL|      0|
|-- Table structur...|     49|        NULL|      0|
|                  --|     50|        NULL|      0|
|                    |     51|        NULL|      0|
|DROP TABLE IF EXI...|     52|        NULL|      0|
|/*!40101 SET @sav...|     53|        NULL|      0|
|/*!40101 SET char...|     54|        NULL|      0|
|                    |     55|        NULL|      0|
|CREATE TABLE `aff...|     56|           1|      1|
|  `id` int(11) NO...|     57|        NULL|      1|
|  `number` varcha...|     58|        NULL|      1|
|  `content` varch...|     59|        NULL|      1|
|  `time` datetime...|     60|        NULL|      1|
|   PRIMARY KEY (`...|     61|        NULL|      1|
|) ENGINE=InnoDB A...|     62|        NULL|      1|
|/*!40101 SET char...|     63|        NULL|      1|
|                    |     64|        NULL|      1|
|                  --|     65|        NULL|      1|
|-- Dumping data f...|     66|           0|      0|
|                  --|     67|        NULL|      0|
|                    |     68|        NULL|      0|
|                    |     84|        NULL|      0|
|-- Dump completed...|     85|        NULL|      0|
+--------------------+-------+------------+-------+
```

My requirement is to extract the DDL portions that occur through out the .sql file into a separate text file.

The solution, I chose is to create a column called "DDL_IND" that marks all the records from the record starting with "CREATE TABLE" string until the record that starts with "-- Dumping data". I have achieved that using the below code.

```
data_source = "s3-path-for-the-58GB-file.sql"

df_userlogs = spark.read.text(data_source)

from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,ArrayType,StructType,StructField
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.orderBy("row_idx")

df_userlogs1 =     df_userlogs.withColumn("row_idx",F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())))

df_userlogs2 = df_userlogs1.withColumn("DDL_IND_TEMP", F.when(F.col("value").startswith("CREATE TABLE") , F.lit(1))
                                                    .when( F.col("value").startswith("-- Dumping data"), F.lit(0))
                                                    .otherwise(F.lit(None))) \
                       .withColumn("DDL_IND",F.when(F.col("value").startswith("CREATE TABLE") , F.lit(1))
                                              .when(F.col("value").startswith("-- Dumping data") , F.lit(0))
                                              .otherwise(F.last("DDL_IND_TEMP",ignorenulls = True).over(w)))`
```

This piece of code runs fine until around 25 GB file but ran into DiskSpill issue during the sort that is required for window for 58 GB file. As there is no column to partition, this is a full file sort it is not able to cope up and issuing below error

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

24/01/23 17:44:58 ERROR TaskMemoryManager: error while calling spill() on org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter@385cbc2a
java.io.IOException: No space left on device

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I am currently testing this on EMR serverless on AWS with application limits as 400 vCPUs, 3000 GB mem, 20 TB GB disk on total which I believe are way high for processing 58 GB file. I am sure I am missing a trick here so its blowing up to the application limits.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, looks like the data I have given above after posting is not nicely formatted where as it is showing nicely if I try to edit in the body of the question. Basically the column "value" contains a text with some lines starting with CREATE TABLE string marking the start of the DDL of a table and next few lines contain the rest of the DDL for the table and after DDL there would a line starting with string "-- Dumping data" marking the end of the DDL for a table. This pattern basically repeats.

Comment: @ Anngva82 Are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula - I am using AWS EMR serverless.

Comment: Hi All, Please help me on the below. I have made some progress on the above. I have ran EMR on EC2 instances with 4 task nodes and each node of 200 GB. I believe, the 200 GB allocation was good enough for the sort operation for window operation without partitions.

Comment: However, when I am running the same code in databricks (using photon jobs compute) with 200 GB dataset with 16 executors ( each 32 GB and 8 cores ) and with autoscaling of auto storage option, it is failing with the below error. +++ org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for s3ablock-0001--e38d3d87-c058-438c-8430-0ec6cb4ae10d with requested size 10485760 as the max capacity in any directory is 0 ++

Comment: I followed this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64342539/problem-could-not-find-any-valid-local-directory-for-s3ablock-0001 and set the values like spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer","bytebuffer")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.active.blocks","6")
spark.conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true") in the notebook but still getting the same error. Did I set up the configs correctly so it changed the upload buffer property from disk to bytebuffer correctly while running? It seems that is not the case, what am I missing here please?

Comment: I tested within a fresh notebook to retrieve the value of upload buffer property using this code and it retrieves None which does not make sense. print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload.buffer"))